# join voice channel when ready (discord.js v12)

Tags: discord.js

I want to make my bot join 2 voice channel in  A different guild or more when the bot ready

> **OK I tried to use it but it doesn't work**

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get['ChannelID1', 'ChannelID2']
  if (!channel) return
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    console.log('Done')
  });
});
```

It doesn't work. I made sure that the ID is right and everything and it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. In line 2 you have to call the function and not get a property of it:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get('id');
  if (!channel) return
  channel.join().then(connection => {
    console.log('Done')
  });
});
```

There is also another problem. It will only join channel 1 because you cannot get two channels at the same time. You can split it up like this:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
  const channels = ['id', 'id']
  for (const channel of channels) {
    const voiceChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channel)
    if (!voiceChannel) continue
    voiceChannel().then(connection => {
      console.log('Done')
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @abdooo9 Thats great! I would really appreciate it if you would accept my answer :-)

Comment: You don't need them to accept an answer. Just click on the grey checkmark.

Comment: I apologize for the delay