# Join an specific voice channel when the bot is ready in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I found some articles about this question. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721124/join-voice-channel-when-ready-discord-js-v12).

But it was in discord v12. I want discord.js v13

My code:

```js
client.on("ready", async() => {
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: "863783336860975114",
            guildId: "847071265100791849",
            adapterCreator: channelId.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })

// It does not work
}
```

How can I make my bot that it joins a specific channel when it's ready?

I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation for [@discordjs/voice](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/stable/general/welcome) an in the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#cheat-sheet) we see:

```js
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: channel.id,
    guildId: channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
```

You need to fetch the guild or channel first since you need to use a [voiceAdapterCreator](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/stable/typedef/CreateVoiceConnectionOptions).

You can use something like [client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client).[channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels).[fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) to get the channel object.

Example code to put inside ready event:

```js
client.channels.fetch(id) // voice channel's id
    .then((channel) => { // channel object

        const VoiceConnection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: channel.id, // the voice channel's id
            guildId: channel.guild.id, // the guild that the channel is in
            adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator // and setting the voice adapter creator
        });
    });
```